# Need to change default date when not selecting a date in matdatepicker

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

When I am not selecting a date in matdatepicker (angular2), it's taking the default value as "01/01/1970", whereas I need to pass 'null' to the method. Can I change the default value somehow?

Code I am using is as below:

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
   <form (ngSubmit)="getEventsByDateRange(f)" #f="ngForm" >
     <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> From : </label>
      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Choose a date" name="fromDate" 
        [(ngModel)]="eventobj.fromDate" #eventDate="ngModel"  required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> To : </label>
      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose a date" name="toDate" 
        [(ngModel)]="eventobj.toDate" #eventDate="ngModel"  required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Submit </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

TS:

```
eventobj = {
fromDate: "Date",
toDate: "Date",
}

 getJobsByDateRange() {
    let fromDate1=new Date(this.eventobj.fromDate)
    let toDate1=new Date(this.eventobj.toDate)

    alert("from :: "+fromDate1+" to :: "+toDate1)
 }
```

If I am clicking on submit button directly then the alert message shows :

> from :: Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to :: Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventobj = {
  fromDate: "Date",
  toDate: "Date",
}
```

Here, you declare strings. But you use dates ...

Anyway, this means that when you do

```
let fromDate1=new Date(this.eventobj.fromDate)
let toDate1=new Date(this.eventobj.toDate)
```

You actually convert a string (being `Date`) to an actual date. You're lucky uou have a date object !

Replace all of that with this :

```
defaultDate = Date.now();

eventobj = {
  fromDate: new Date(this.defaultDate - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7), // One week
  toDate: new Date(this.defaultDate),
}

getJobsByDateRange() {
  let fromDate1 = this.eventobj.fromDate;
  let toDate1 = this.eventobj.toDate;
  alert("from :: "+fromDate1+" to :: "+toDate1)
}
```

Comment: When I am refreshing the page, it's holding the value. How can I make it blank after it's refreshed?

Comment: I don't know, it should not keep the value ... Are you storing the value in the local storage or in a database ?

Comment: I'm storing it in local variable